# How to create an unsigned char array in Python? (For glReadPixels using PyOpenGL)

Tags: python, opengl-es, ctypes, pyopengl

I have written some code in GLES2 and EGL using PyOpenGL, I need to use the glReadPixels function except the last argument must be a ctypes unsigned char buffer which I'm not sure how to create.

Here is the C code:

```
unsigned char* buffer = malloc(width * height * 4);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

What would the equivalent Python code be?

I am using GLES2 and not GL, therefore, `buffer = glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)` does not work.

When I try `buffer = glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)` I get the following error:

```
   buffer = glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
  File "/home/fa/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
TypeError: this function takes at least 7 arguments (6 given)
```

Comment: bytearray or bytes

Comment: This is really dependent on the API of your wrapper library. In general, one does not work with primitive arrays in Python, unless you are working directly with a C foreign function interface.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `TypeError: one character bytes, bytearray or integer expected` I get this if I pass a random datatype to the last argument, does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a byte buffer with the proper size:

```py
buffer_size = width * height * 4
buffer = (GLbyte * buffer_size)()
```

Pass the buffer glReadPixels:

```py
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer)
```

---

That's the same as using `ctypes.c_byte`:

```py
import ctypes
```

```py
buffer_size = width * height * 4
buffer = (ctypes.c_byte * buffer_size)()
```

---

Or create a numpy buffer with the proper size:

```py
import numpy
```

```py
buffer = numpy.empty(width * height * 4, "uint8")
```

Pass the buffer `glReadPixels`:

```py
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer)
```

Comment: I got the following error:    
`glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer)
  File "/home/fa/berryconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenGL/platform/baseplatform.py", line 415, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 7: <class 'TypeError'>: byref() argument must be a ctypes instance, not '_ctypes.PyCArrayType'`

Comment: @AdishRao Last try, then I'll give up: `buffer = numpy.empty(width * height * 4, "uint8")`

Comment: @AdishRao  `buffer = (GLbyte * buffer_size)()` and `buffer = (ctypes.c_byte * buffer_size)()` works, too. The braces were missing before. (I feel dumb)